# job scheduler issue in oracle

Tags: oracle, scheduler, jobs

I have created following job

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job(
  job_name => 'DAILY_BACKUP',
  job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
  job_action => 'DB_BACKUP',
  start_date => sysdate,
  repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=23',
  enabled => TRUE,
  comments => 'Runtime: Every day at 11:00 pm');
end;
```

I can see the job has been enabled

```
  select job_name, enabled from user_scheduler_jobs;
 JOB_NAME                       ENABL
------------------------------ -----
DAILY_BACKUP                   TRUE
```

I can see the execution log in user_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG as well

```
select log_date, substr( job_name, 1, 30 )job_name, owner, status from user_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG;
    LOG_DATE                                                                    JOB_NAME                                                                                                                 OWNER                          STATUS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
26-SEP-16 11.54.14.755972 PM +00:00                                         DAILY_BACKUP                                                                                                             BACKUP                         SUCCEEDED
27-SEP-16 02.02.32.603195 AM +00:00                                         DAILY_BACKUP                                                                                                             BACKUP                         SUCCEEDED
27-SEP-16 11.54.14.835203 PM +00:00                                         DAILY_BACKUP                                                                                                             BACKUP                         SUCCEEDED
```

the Second row in user_scheduler_job_log was created when I ran the job manually.

but the table data that should have been updated by the procedure db_backup is not updated.
The table data gets updated when I run the job manually using

```
      exec dbms_scheduler.run_job('DAILY_BACKUP');
```

I have done the parameter level check suggested in this URL number of processes, number of sessions seem to be fine.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/648581

I might have been missing very basic thing, kindly guide me what is wrong with my job?

Here is the code for db_backup

```
   create or replace procedure db_backup as

 cursor cur_listOfTables is
    select table_name from backuplog where backup_flag = 'Y';

  v_truncate_query varchar2(4000);
 v_insert_query varchar2(4000);
 v_current_function varchar2(200);

 v_disable_constraint_success number := 0;
 v_truncate_success number := 0;
 v_insert_success number := 0;
 v_enable_constraint_success number := 0;

 v_schema_to_backup varchar2(50) := 'PRODSCHEMA';

 begin

  v_current_function := $$PLSQL_UNIT;

  v_disable_constraint_success := alter_all_fk_constraints( v_schema_to_backup, 'D');

  for backup_rec in cur_listOfTables
  loop
    v_truncate_query := 'truncate table ' || backup_rec.table_name;

    v_insert_query := 'insert into ' || backup_rec.table_name || ' select * from ' || backup_rec.table_name || '@prod';

    --v_disable_constraint_success := alter_fk_constraints( backup_rec.table_name, 'D' );

    if v_disable_constraint_success = 0 then
            begin
                    execute immediate v_truncate_query;
                    exception
                            when others then
                                    log_error( v_current_function, backup_rec.table_name, sqlcode, sqlerrm);
                                    v_truncate_success := 1;
            end;

            if v_truncate_success = 0 then
                    begin
                            execute immediate v_insert_query;
                            exception
                                    when others then
                                    log_error( v_current_function, backup_rec.table_name, sqlcode, sqlerrm);
                                    v_insert_success := 1;
                    end;
                    if v_insert_success = 0 then
                            update backuplog set last_backup_date = sysdate where table_name = backup_rec.table_name;
                            commit;
                    end if;
            end if;

            --v_enable_constraint_success := alter_fk_constraints( backup_rec.table_name, 'E' );

    end if;

    --dbms_output.put_line(v_truncate_query);
    --dbms_output.put_line(v_insert_query);
end loop;


  v_enable_constraint_success := alter_all_fk_constraints( v_schema_to_backup, 'E');
 reset_all_sequences(v_schema_to_backup);

 end;
```

Comment: Could you please provide the contents of `db_backup` procedure?

Comment: Hi @JSapkota I have added the code for db_backup in the question

Comment: *start_date => sysdate*. Maybe you need set *to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate,'dd.mm.yyyy') || ' 23:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' )*

Comment: HI @SkyWalker I will do the changes and update you the findings.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time to look into my problem and suggest the workarounds. Actually I just added the schema name in job_action attribute and the job was running normally.